# Which test to use? looking for approval

Tags: python, t-test, chi-squared-test

I have a multiple categorized table. The columns are three+- categories which I want to compare (pairwise  - 2 each time). For instance:

```
Categories       | Alpha + | Beta + | Alpha -
Total population | 630     | 45     | 127
Stage 1          | 124     | 12     | 17
Stage 2          | 45      | 19     | 28
Stage 3          | 234     | 4      | 2
Stage 4          | 64      | 5      | 10
Unknown          | 163     | 5      | 70
```

The N (total population) is different. How would I know that between the ratio between Alpha+ & Beta+ in Stage 2 is significantly different?
I thought about T test because the data isn't a-parametric

*Edited ->
Is stage 1 in alpha+ is significantly lower/higher in ratio than stage 1 beta +? taking in account that alpha + total population is 630 and in stage 1 there are 124 people out of 630 while beta+ population is 45, there are 12 people in stage 1. Same about each stage, individually.

Comment: Chi-squared test on counts, not t test. See my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a chi-squared test for homogeneity.
Let's compare A+ and B+. The test is a bit difficult because
counts for 'Stage5' and 'Unknown' are so small for B+. The null hypothesis is that the (proportions of) 'Stages' are similarly distributed in A+ and B+.

This test requires a contingence table such as `TAB` below:

```
A = c(124, 45, 234, 64, 163)
B = c(12, 19, 4, 5, 5)
sum(A); sum(B)
[1] 630
[1] 45
TAB = rbind(A,B);   TAB
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
A  124   45  234   64  163
B   12   19    4    5    5
```

Then in R, `chisq.test` gives the following output:

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 68.75, df = 4, p-value = 4.166e-14

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The expected counts $E_{ij}$ for this test are found from row and column
totals based on the null hypothesis that the 'Stage' distributions
are the same for A+ and B+. If all of the $E_{ij} > 5,$ then the chi-squared
statistic $Q = 68.75:$ $$Q = \sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=1}^2\frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}} 
\stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = (5-1)(2-1_ = 4),$$
where $X_{ij}$ are entries in `TAB`.

For your data the $E_{ij}$ are shown below. Notice that the row for B has
two counts barely below $5.$ Thus, the very small P-value, indicating that
$H_0$ should be rejected, may not be accurate. Even so, no $E_{ij}$ is much less than $5,$ and the P-value is very far below 5%. So it one can guess that rejecting $H_0$
is the correct decision.

```
chisq.test(TAB)$exp
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3] [,4]  [,5]
A 126.933333 59.733333 222.13333 64.4 156.8
B   9.066667  4.266667  15.86667  4.6  11.2
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

However, the implementation of `chisq.test` in R, permits simulating
a more accurate P-value (using parameter `sim=T`), so guessing is not necessary.
The accurate P-value is $0.0005 < 0.01 = 1\%$ and we may reject at the 1% level
of significance.

```
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
         with simulated p-value 
          (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 68.75, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

*Notes:* You can find a description of the chi-squared test of homogeneity
in most applied statistics books. In case you are not familiar with the
method of computing the $E_{ij},$ the R code below illustrates computation
of $E_{11} = 126.933333.$ Other expected counts are found similarly. "Row total times column total divided by grand total." (Do not round expected counts to integers when computing $Q.)$

```
rowSums(TAB)
  A   B 
630  45 
colSums(TAB)
[1] 136  64 238  69 168
sum(TAB)
[1] 675
630*136/675
[1] 126.9333
```

Comment: I am using python tbh but the main idea is clear , I will try it and see how it goes, thanks

Comment: Could I just clarify the simulation step method (a good tool to avoid merging cells to increase low cell counts!)? What I think it does is it uses the proportions from the actuals and draws 675 times from this distribution. It then run the chi-squared test against these simulated values. It repeats this 2000 times and then takes the average p-value. Is this the method it uses?

Comment: Bruce, the problem is that I am trying to find the "difference" between each row individually and regardless to the other rows (which is Xij if I understood correctly?)

Comment: In your question you say 'ratio' and now you say 'difference', sounds imprecise at best, confusing at worst.  // Are the numbers 124, 45, etc. _counts_? // Please say **_in plain English_** what are `alpha+`, `beta+`, and `alpha-`? What are 'Stages'? What do you want to know? // Please edit Question so it is self-contained and clear,

Comment: If applicable at all (normal dist'n would be in question), what a paired t test on two columns could tell you is that the numbers in first col are bigger than corresp, ones in 2nd; that's pretty clear without a statistical test. [if you want a test, in five times out of five, 2nd row is smaller, P-value $1/2^5 = 1/32 < 0.05 = 5\%.]$

Comment: Edited, the comparison is between the columns, each row is independent. Stage x - > how many people in stage x.

Comment: To the extent that I understand your Edit, I stand by my suggestion to use a chi-squared test, instead of t test. If Stage2 cases where of the same proportion in `A+` and `B+` then we would see (expected) counts about 60 and 4 instead of (observed) 45 and 19.